# How to configure a Component/Autowire with conditions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to configure the autowire or the component class so that the `runThis(string)` gets called without the parameter (`runThis()`) and through the autowire, spring automatically knows which string to use based on what class its being called from (each class will always use the same unique string)

```java
@Component
public class SomeDao {
    public void runThis(String withThis){
        ...
    }
}

public class Foo {
    @Autowired
    private SomeDao dao;

    private static final String HI = "hi";

    public String getSomething(){
        dao.runThis(HI);
    }
}

public class Bar {
    @Autowired
    private SomeDao dao;

    private static final String BYE = "bye";

    public String getSomething(){
        dao.runThis(BYE);
    }
}
```

something like an @Autowire("hi") or just @Autowire with a config class/function somewhere

Comment: The way you're doing it now is the correct way to do it. Your idea is really not a good one. Stay with your current solution.

Comment: thanks, I'll stick with this, but just for the sake of like a proof of concept, is there a way to accomplish this? or does it not exist because it's not a good idea to do so?

Comment: Assuming those services are used to serve HTTP requests, you would need to store the string inside a request-scoped bean injected in the services and the DAO. But that is way less clear, intuitive, readable, testable than simply passing an argument.

Comment: Autowired classes are singletons that get created when the application is started. So they dont per default get injected during runtime. What you can do is constructor injection and in the constructor pass in your variable. Or define 2 beans at startup configured in 2 ways and then qualify them and inject bean A in class A and bean B in class B. But all of this is more verbose than your choice above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current way of doing this is the right way